# What method is used to make the open button in FileDialog work?

Tags: java, file-io, filedialog

```
JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu file = new JMenu("File");  
add(menubar,BorderLayout.NORTH); 
menubar.add(file);              
JMenuItem Open = new JMenuItem("OPEN...     Ctrl+O");
file.add(Open);
Open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
        Frame f = new Frame();
        FileDialog openf = new FileDialog(f, "Open");
        openf.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Well, I tried to use a lot many examples on the internet which makes the open button work as you can see i have already made the design but i need help in how to open a .txt file on clicking the open button in the filedialog. how am i supposed to do that?? i would really appreciate if anyone can help me out with few lines of code that actually works as i am sick of searching error generating codes from the internet.

[image]

Comment: It depends how you want to open it. Do you want to open the file inside a text box in your Java program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) states:

> The FileDialog class displays a dialog window from which the user can
>   select a file.
>
> Since it is a modal dialog, when the application calls its show method
>   to display the dialog, it blocks the rest of the application until the
>   user has chosen a file.

Therefore, instead of calling `.setVisible(true)` you can call `.show()` on the dialog, and then you can use [getFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getFile%28%29) to get the file that was chosen, or [getFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getFiles%28%29) if you are using [multipleMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#setMultipleMode%28boolean%29).

To read the file you can use:

```
public static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
  return encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
}

yourComponent.setText(readFile(openf.getFile(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
```

(Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file))